# How can I hang a picture without being able to drive nails/hooks into the wall?

Tags: home

I have some pictures I'd like to hang on my wall, but I can't drive nails into it due to the conditions of my lease.

They're both rather heavy, one is about 1kg (2lbs) and the other is probably 2-3kg (5-7lbs), including the frame (or I suppose, mostly the frame).

What's the best way to hang them?

Comment: Not a lifehack, so I can't really post this as an answer, but you might as well get some of [these](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Command-Picture-Hanging-Strips-Value/dp/B000OF6X48) 3D Command hanging strips. They don't leave any marks, But I suppose they're only as strong as the paint is. Might be worth looking into.

Comment: [3M Command Strips](https://www.command.com/3M/en_US/command/products/?N=5924736+3291751908+3294529207&rt=rud) is another option. The product is described to support up to 9kg for "damage-free hanging".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many different types of adhesives can be very useful in this situation. Something that I've seen used a lot is [adhesive putty](http://www.amazon.com/b?node=490663011) also known as sticky tack. Adhesive putty is a bunch of small strips of a sticky substance a bit like dough that is commonly used to hold things up. You'll want to roll them up in little balls, then stick them on the corners of the photo frame, then put it on the walls. You may need to add the putty in more places if the picture is too heavy.

[image]

Comment: Taking the puddy off the wall without taking the paint with it can be tough.  I would recommend using a blow dryer to heat up the puddy before removal.

Answer (score 3):

In [this answer](//lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/7281/4490) I describe various alternatives for how to hang something on a wall.

In your case you might need something tolerating a heavier load, and my suggestion to you is that if you have wooden lists in the roof you could possible attach nails either to the list itself or wedged in between the list and the wall or roof. Then you attach strings to the nails and hang your picture from these. This method will leave virtually no marks and should be allowed by your current lease options.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, this isn't "hanging" a picture, but if your goal is to display pictures or artwork up against to wall without nail holes, an easel is another option.

[image] [image]